# Using a switch and a pc to test the ports of another switch that resides in a device I wish to test

Tags: switch, testing, automation

I have a PC and a switch, lets call it the Tester.  There is a device I wish to test which has an internal computer and a network switch. Let's call it the Device. The Device has 16 network ports that all come from its internal switch. I need to verify the operation and signal integrity of the ports on the Device.  A suggestion I have is to connect all the ports of the Device to ports on the Tester, and run some kind of program to verify the Device ports function.  Is this possible?  I do not think this is a viable situation with a level 2 switch, but maybe possible with a level 3.

An alternative I have is to create a Tester with 16 network ports. I feel this is more desirable. Is it better and if so, why?

The desired outcome is to create an automated Tester when the test operator connects all the wires and starts the test.  The test will produce PASS/FAIL for each of the 16 Device ports.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to verify the operation and signal integrity of the ports on the Device.

You can verify operation with a simple software test but you can't verify (analog) *signal* integrity without special equipment.

A managed switch could be used to monitor *frame* integrity (by checking its port FCS error counter). Without a counter on the switch you can only check for missing packets that you expect to be received.

> run some kind of program to verify the Device ports function. Is this possible?

Should be - programming and product recommendations are explicitly off topic here though.

> I do not think this is a viable situation with a level 2 switch, but maybe possible with a level 3.

A *layer-3* switch certainly requires configuration for that, a "more elaborate setup". Without configuration, there's no difference between a layer-2 and a layer-3 switch. Of course, "layer 3" means IPv4 or IPv6 that your device needs to speak.

> An alternative I have is to create a Tester with 16 network ports.

That won't work without a more elaborate setup. With simple switches or unconfigured, managed ones, multiple links between switches create a bridge loop, causing a broadcast storm and bringing down the network. So, the simple method is to test ports sequentially.

We could perhaps provide more specific help if you would tell us more about the device in your question.

Comment: Sorry about the "level" brain typo..  I think you basically answered the question.  A switch with multiple links to another switch causes a loop.  Using a layer-3 switch to create a VLAN on 16 ports on the Tester switch seems to make for a complicated test setup as opposed to just putting 16 eth interfaces on the Tester PC (using a NI PXI chassis loaded with 4 quad port ethernet cards)

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to programmatically activate/deactivate each port in sequence and run your test loop in between. You could also use individual VLANs and trunk them to your tester which then loops through the subinterfaces. Or 16 NICs, of course - many ways to do it really.